# Flex AIR: Installer file is damaged

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

**UPDATE:**

I tried exporting the AIR app again as an EXE and now I'm getting this error:

Error creating native installer file: Could not generate timestamp: Connection timed out: connect.

i researched this error and saw the fix is to do the following (because my system uses a proxy):

Here: [Adobe Flash Builder 4 folder]\jre\lib\net.properties

set: java.net.useSystemProxies=true if you want to use the system proxy, or specify it manually.

I have done this on the net.properties in the Adobe folder and for each JRE I have installed on my system...to no avail.

**ORIGINAL POST:**

Is there something else that could cause this problem?

I'm using a tutorial here: http://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/deploying-air-application-with-air-runtimeredistributable-in-single-exe/....

....to build an install file using a program called InstallJammer.

This tutorial has you do the following things:

- Export your AIR app as an EXE file.
- Place this EXE file, the AdobeAIRInstaller.exe, and any 3rd party EXE files into a ZIP file.
- At this point you switch to your installer program (InstallShield or InstallJammer) and you create the actions that will do the following:
- Unzip the zip file you created
- Execute the AdobeAIRInstaller.exe, your AIR app EXE, and any other 3rd party EXE files.

When I go by this tutorial the AdobeAIRInstaller.exe installs just fine, my 3rd party EXE installs just fine, but I get the following error when installing my AIR app EXE:

*The application could not be installed because the installer file is damaged. Try obtaining a new installer file from the application author.*

If I run my AIR app EXE on its own, after exporting the release build, it installs just fine.

Why is it that the EXE file would work fine on its own but throw an error saying the installer file is damaged when I try and run it from an Install program?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Comment: It may be easier to understand what the issue is if you expand on what you're doing.  I don't want to try to dissect the tutorial you found and try to find out what steps are tripping you up. I'm sure I'm not the only one. Bring the relevant bits from the tutorial into your question and tell us "I did This"

Comment: Understood. I just added the exact details of what I'm doing.

Comment: Hi don't have an exact answer, but I was receiving this when I tried packaging for Mac on a Windows machine, only to find out that isn't possible, but anywho here's a link that might lead to some helpful logs: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403150.html#main_probs-windows

Comment: Also something to consider is the user that is considered the host of the process.  I would check this out in the Task Manager and see if there's any difference (as in started by you has your username versus SYSTEM when started by the installer or something).  Aside from differences in user permissions the only other thing I can think of is it truly got corrupted, can you use an extraction tool to pull the AIR installer back out of the final and test it?

Comment: I don't think it got corrupted because if I pull the exe out of the zip file and run it, it installs the AIR app just fine. But if I let the Installer try to run the exe as part of it's process, it fails.

Comment: Shaun, that link you gave was very helpful, thank you. I tried re-exporting my AIR app to an EXE and was getting problems. I updated my original post with what I did. Seems like because I am using a proxy to connect to the internet I am having issues creating the timestamp to get a good installer file. That is the point of failure now.

Comment: One thing to ADD: My version of AIR is 2.6 but my runtime is 3.1. Could that be a possible problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: The error message appears when you have previously installations of the AIR app on your computer. You have to go under add/remove programs and remove each instance of your AIR app and then you'll be able to install the files. Wow, did I waste a lot of time on that!!